# For MapReduce jobs, is using 1 machine with 4 cores the same as using 4 machines with 1 core?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, google-cloud-platform

I am creating a cluster on Google Cloud and they asked me to choose how many machines I want to use and how many cores should be on each machine.  If I want to run MapReduce jobs, is there a practical difference between asking for 8 machines with 1 core each and asking for 2 machines with 4 cores each?

Answer (score 2):

Your question in the title and in the body are different.

When choosing between 4x1core and 1x4core, the latter has an advantage of data locality - there is no data transfer between mappers and reducers, all data is on the same machine.

Another important factor to consider is the amount of RAM. If you have to choose between 1 machine with 16GB RAM and 8 machines with 2 GB RAM,   you'd better go with the first option, because some algorithms require to load a lot of stuff in memory and with small RAM you will be unable to run them.

Last thing to remember: it's important to have same configurations for all machines in the cluster, otherwise some will finish earlier and wait for the slow ones. If cluster will grow, choose most suitable configuration now.

Long story short: in most scenarios higher tier machines will perform better. Choose them if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the information, that was very helpful!  Also, it is possible to have four mappers run on the same machine, if the machine has four cores?  Is there anything special I have to do to use all of the cores, or will Hadoop do it automatically?

Comment: @Jessica yes, it is possible. usually you declare mapper resources before job start, so you can say mapper needs 2gb ram and 1 core by default and hadoop will spawn 8 mappers if it has 16gb ram and 8 cores available. you can google YARN (hadoop resource manager) and check how it works.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSkywalker!